# Laravel class 'Form' not found

Tags: laravel, laravelcollective

I have a problem with Laravel Form & HTML. I ran Composer.

`composer require illuminate/html`

It worked just fine and I added `Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class,` to my app.php. I also added `'Form' => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class,` and `'Html'=> Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade::class,` to my aliases  but I still get an error.

> FatalErrorException in 792badfd9bd1a291ca2af663e544784e7ea6712c.php
>   line 6: Class 'Form' not found

Comment: Provide more info, there are ~5 versions of laravel.

Comment: i'm using "illuminate/html": "^5.0",

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer you better check the laravelcollective package

Answer (score 1):

Better would be to use https://laravelcollective.com/ since the `illuminate/html` is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

`Form` is not a class in `Illuminate\Html`. You're probably looking for `FormBuilder`.

Comment: He is adding an alias as Facade.

Comment: Hmmm...the way the question is worded I assumed he was attempting to use `Illuminate\Html` in a composer project without Laravel. If he is using `Laravel`, shouldn't `Form` be available by default?

Comment: Well, facade's refer to an accessor which will refer to a short name that will be registered in the service provider so that laravel can save it in it's container for static calls. If you were to check the service provider it contains a binding between the value from `getFacadeAccessor` method of the facade and the FormBuilder class.